# Фильтрация таблицы с помощью QSortFilterProxyModel

Tags: c++, qt, qtcreator

В общем проблема такая. У меня есть таблица которая основана на базе данных. В этой таблице мне нужно реализовать множественную фильтрацию.
Я сделал над каждым столбцом поле для ввода фильтра пользователем но при попытке ввода двух фильтров (например в 2 столбца) работает только один из них.
Уже всю голову сломал и не понимаю как мне использовать класс customfiltersort который унаследован от класса QSortFilterProxyModel, чтобы всё-таки реализовать множественную фильтрацию
[image: множественная фильтрация не работает]

В основе модели лежит QSqlTableModel
Ссылка на проект Qt Creator:
https://yadi.sk/d/3yk_O2R4kjwDrA v.3
https://yadi.sk/d/vHxmZZ3fAc77TQ v.2

Класс mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "customfiltersort.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    /* Первым делом необходимо создать объект, который будет использоваться для работы с данными нашей БД
     * и инициализировать подключение к базе данных
     * */
    db = new DataBase();
    db->connectToDataBase();

    /* После чего производим наполнение таблицы базы данных
     * контентом, который будет отображаться в TableView
     * */
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        QVariantList data;
        int random = qrand(); // Получаем случайные целые числа для вставки а базу данных
        data.append(QDate::currentDate()); // Получаем текущую дату для вставки в БД
        data.append(QTime::currentTime()); // Получаем текущее время для вставки в БД
        // Подготавливаем полученное случайное число для вставки в БД
        data.append(random);
        // Подготавливаем сообщение для вставки в базу данных
        data.append("Получено сообщение от " + QString::number(random));
        // Вставляем данные в БД
        db->inserIntoTable(data);
    }

    /* Инициализируем модель для представления данных
     * с заданием названий колонок
     * */
    this->setupModel(TABLE,
                     QStringList() << trUtf8("id")
                                   << trUtf8("Дата")
                                   << trUtf8("Время")
                                   << trUtf8("Рандомное число")
                                   << trUtf8("Сообщение")
               );

    /* Инициализируем внешний вид таблицы с данными
     * */
    this->createUI();
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

/* Метод для инициализации модеи представления данных
 * */
void MainWindow::setupModel(const QString &tableName, const QStringList &headers)
{
    /* Производим инициализацию модели представления данных
     * с установкой имени таблицы в базе данных, по которому
     * будет производится обращение в таблице
     * */
    model = new QSqlTableModel(this);
    model->setTable(tableName);

    /* Устанавливаем названия колонок в таблице с сортировкой данных
     * */
    for(int i = 0, j = 0; i < model->columnCount(); i++, j++){
        model->setHeaderData(i,Qt::Horizontal,headers[j]);
    }
    // Устанавливаем сортировку по возрастанию данных по нулевой колонке
    model->setSort(0,Qt::AscendingOrder);
}

void MainWindow::createUI()
{
    proxyModel = new SMuliFilterProxyModel(this);
    proxyModel->setSourceModel(model);

    ui->tableView->setModel(proxyModel);// Устанавливаем модель на TableView
    ui->tableView->setSortingEnabled(true);
    ui->tableView->setColumnHidden(0, true);    // Скрываем колонку с id записей
    // Разрешаем выделение строк
    ui->tableView->setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView::SelectRows);
    // Устанавливаем режим выделения лишь одно строки в таблице
    ui->tableView->setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::SingleSelection);
    // Устанавливаем размер колонок по содержимому
    ui->tableView->resizeColumnsToContents();
    ui->tableView->setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView::NoEditTriggers);
    ui->tableView->horizontalHeader()->setStretchLastSection(true); 
    model->select(); // Делаем выборку данных из таблицы
}

void MainWindow::on_lineEdit_textChanged(const QString &arg1)
{
    proxyModel->beginSorting();
    proxyModel->setFilterValue(1,arg1);
}

void MainWindow::on_lineEdit_2_textChanged(const QString &arg1)
{
    proxyModel->beginSorting();
    proxyModel->setFilterValue(2,arg1);
}

void MainWindow::on_lineEdit_3_textChanged(const QString &arg1)
{
    proxyModel->beginSorting();
    proxyModel->setFilterValue(3,arg1);
}

void MainWindow::on_lineEdit_4_textChanged(const QString &arg1)
{
    proxyModel->beginSorting();
    proxyModel->setFilterValue(4,arg1);
}
```

Класс main.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Класс database.cpp

```
#include "database.h"

DataBase::DataBase(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{

}

DataBase::~DataBase()
{

}

/* Методы для подключения к базе данных
 * */
void DataBase::connectToDataBase()
{
    /* Перед подключением к базе данных производим проверку на её существование.
     * В зависимости от результата производим открытие базы данных или её восстановление
     * */
    if(!QFile("C:/example/" DATABASE_NAME).exists()){
        this->restoreDataBase();
    } else {
        this->openDataBase();
    }
}

/* Методы восстановления базы данных
 * */
bool DataBase::restoreDataBase()
{
    if(this->openDataBase()){
        if(!this->createTable()){
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    } else {
        qDebug() << "Не удалось восстановить базу данных";
        return false;
    }
    return false;
}

/* Метод для открытия базы данных
 * */
bool DataBase::openDataBase()
{
    /* База данных открывается по заданному пути
     * и имени базы данных, если она существует
     * */
    db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
    db.setHostName(DATABASE_HOSTNAME);
    db.setDatabaseName("C:/example/" DATABASE_NAME);
    if(db.open()){
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

/* Методы закрытия базы данных
 * */
void DataBase::closeDataBase()
{
    db.close();
}

/* Метод для создания таблицы в базе данных
 * */
bool DataBase::createTable()
{
    /* В данном случае используется формирование сырого SQL-запроса
     * с последующим его выполнением.
     * */
    QSqlQuery query;
    if(!query.exec( "CREATE TABLE " TABLE " ("
                            "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                            TABLE_DATE      " DATE            NOT NULL,"
                            TABLE_TIME      " TIME            NOT NULL,"
                            TABLE_RANDOM    " INTEGER         NOT NULL,"
                            TABLE_MESSAGE   " VARCHAR(255)    NOT NULL"
                        " )"
                    )){
        qDebug() << "DataBase: error of create " << TABLE;
        qDebug() << query.lastError().text();
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

/* Метод для вставки записи в базу данных
 * */
bool DataBase::inserIntoTable(const QVariantList &data)
{
    /* Запрос SQL формируется из QVariantList,
     * в который передаются данные для вставки в таблицу.
     * */
    QSqlQuery query;
    /* В начале SQL запрос формируется с ключами,
     * которые потом связываются методом bindValue
     * для подстановки данных из QVariantList
     * */
    query.prepare("INSERT INTO " TABLE " ( " TABLE_DATE ", "
                                             TABLE_TIME ", "
                                             TABLE_RANDOM ", "
                                             TABLE_MESSAGE " ) "
                  "VALUES (:Date, :Time, :Random, :Message )");
    query.bindValue(":Date",        data[0].toDate());
    query.bindValue(":Time",        data[1].toTime());
    query.bindValue(":Random",      data[2].toInt());
    query.bindValue(":Message",     data[3].toString());
    // После чего выполняется запросом методом exec()
    if(!query.exec()){
        qDebug() << "error insert into " << TABLE;
        qDebug() << query.lastError().text();
        return false;
    } else {
    return true;
}
return false;
```

}

Класс customfiltersort.cpp

```
#include "customfiltersort.h"
#include <QSortFilterProxyModel>

CustomFilterSort::CustomFilterSort(QObject *parent) : QSortFilterProxyModel(parent)
{
}

void CustomFilterSort::setFilterFixedString(const QString &pattern)
{
  if(!filters.contains(pattern)) // Если фильтр не содержится в списке фильтров
    {
      filters.append(pattern); // Добавляем его в список фильтров
    }
  qDebug() << "Добавление фильтра: " << filters;
  invalidateFilter();
}

 void CustomFilterSort::removeFilter(QString value)
 {
   if(filters.contains(value)) // Если фильтр есть в списке фильтров
     {
       filters.removeAll(value); // Удаляем его из списка фильтров
     }
     qDebug() << "Удаление фильтра: " << filters;
     invalidateFilter();
 }

bool CustomFilterSort::filterAcceptsRow(int sourceRow, const QModelIndex &sourceParent) const
{
  QModelIndex index = sourceModel()->index(sourceRow, filterKeyColumn(), sourceParent);

  foreach (QString f, filters) // Поиск фильтра в строке
    {
      if(sourceModel()->data(index).toString().contains(f)) // Если какой-либо фильтр присутствует в строке
      {
         return sourceModel()->data(index).toString().contains(f);
       }
    }
return false;
}
```

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QSqlTableModel>
/* Подключаем заголовочный файл для работы с информацией, которая помещена в базу данных */
#include "database.h"
#include <QSortFilterProxyModel>
#include "smulifilterproxymodel.h"

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:

    void on_lineEdit_textChanged(const QString &arg1);

    void on_lineEdit_2_textChanged(const QString &arg1);

    void on_lineEdit_3_textChanged(const QString &arg1);

    void on_lineEdit_4_textChanged(const QString &arg1);

private:
    Ui::MainWindow  *ui;
    /* В проекте используются объекты для взаимодействия с информацией в базе данных
     * и моделью представления таблицы базы данных
     * */
    DataBase        *db;
    QSqlTableModel  *model;
    SMuliFilterProxyModel *proxyModel;
    //QSortFilterProxyModel *proxyModel;

private:
    /* Также присутствуют два метода, которые формируют модель
     * и внешний вид TableView
     * */
    void setupModel(const QString &tableName, const QStringList &headers);
    void createUI();
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

database.h

```
#ifndef DATABASE_H
#define DATABASE_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QSql>
#include <QSqlQuery>
#include <QSqlError>
#include <QSqlDatabase>
#include <QFile>
#include <QDate>
#include <QDebug>

/* Директивы имен таблицы, полей таблицы и базы данных */
#define DATABASE_HOSTNAME   "ExampleDataBase"
#define DATABASE_NAME       "DataBase.db"

#define TABLE                   "TableExample"
#define TABLE_DATE              "Date"
#define TABLE_TIME              "Time"
#define TABLE_MESSAGE           "Message"
#define TABLE_RANDOM            "Random"

class DataBase : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit DataBase(QObject *parent = 0);
    ~DataBase();
    /* Методы для непосредственной работы с классом
     * Подключение к базе данных и вставка записей в таблицу
     * */
    void connectToDataBase();
    bool inserIntoTable(const QVariantList &data);

private:
    // Сам объект базы данных, с которым будет производиться работа
    QSqlDatabase    db;

private:
    /* Внутренние методы для работы с базой данных
     * */
    bool openDataBase();
    bool restoreDataBase();
    void closeDataBase();
    bool createTable();
};

#endif // DATABASE_H
```

customfiltersort.h

```
#ifndef CUSTOMFILTERSORT_H
#define CUSTOMFILTERSORT_H

#include "QSortFilterProxyModel"
#include "QStringList"
#include "QMessageBox"
#include <QtDebug>

class CustomFilterSort : public QSortFilterProxyModel
{
  Q_OBJECT

public:
  CustomFilterSort(QObject *parent = 0);

  void setFilterFixedString(const QString &pattern);
  void removeFilter(QString value);
  bool filterAcceptsRow(int sourceRow, const QModelIndex &sourceParent) const;

private:
  QStringList filters;
};

#endif // CUSTOMFILTERSORT_H
```

Класс smulifilterproxymodel.cpp

```
#include "smulifilterproxymodel.h"

SMuliFilterProxyModel::SMuliFilterProxyModel(QObject *parent)
    : QSortFilterProxyModel(parent)
{
    stringEkvival = QString::fromUtf8(
                        "АA "
                        "БB "
                        "ВV "
                        "ГG "
                        "ДD "
                        "ЕE "
                        "ЗZ "
                        "ИI "
                        "ЙJ "
                        "КK "
                        "ЛL "
                        "МM "
                        "НN "
                        "ОO "
                        "ПP "
                        "РR "
                        "СS "
                        "ТT "
                        "УU "
                        "ФF "
                        "ХH "
                        "ЦC "
                        "ЫY ");

}

bool SMuliFilterProxyModel::filterAcceptsRow(int sourceRow,
        const QModelIndex &sourceParent) const
{
    bool res = true;
    QHashIterator<int, QRegExp> it(filterData);

    while (it.hasNext())
    {
        it.next();
        res = res && sourceModel()->data(
                        sourceModel()->index(
                                sourceRow, it.key(), sourceParent
                        )
                ).toString().contains(it.value());

    }

    return res;
}

QString SMuliFilterProxyModel::_RegExpString(const QString _value) const
{
    if (_value.isEmpty())
    {    return QString();    }

    QString _val = _value;
    QString _valP = "";
    QString res;

    res += "(("+_val+")|";

    QRegExp re("[A-Z]");
    int notFound;
    int idx = notFound;
    int cnt = _val.size();
    for (int i=0; i<cnt; ++i)
    {
      // проверяем входит ли символ в заменяемые, Рус En не важно
        idx = stringEkvival.indexOf(_val.at(i));

        if (idx == notFound)
        {    _val.replace(i, 1, " ");    }        // не входит - ставим пробел
        else
        {
          // входит - смотрим это англ или русский симавол
            if (re.indexIn(_val.at(i)) == notFound)
            {    ++idx;    }    // если == -1 то русский => нужно взять следующий символ из строки замены
            else
            {    --idx;    }    // если != -1 то английский => нужно взять предыдущий символ из строки замены

            _val.replace(i, 1, stringEkvival.at(idx));
        }
    }
    res += "("+_val+"))";

    return res;
}
```

smulifilterproxymodel.h

```
#ifndef SMULIFILTERPROXYMODEL_H
#define SMULIFILTERPROXYMODEL_H

#include "QSortFilterProxyModel"
#include "QStringList"
#include "QMessageBox"
#include <QtDebug>

class SMuliFilterProxyModel : public QSortFilterProxyModel
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    SMuliFilterProxyModel(QObject *parent = 0);

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------
    void clear(int _col)
    {
        if (_col == -1)
        {    filterData.clear();    }
        else
        {    filterData.remove(_col);    }

        invalidateFilter();
    }
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------
    void removeFilter(int _col)
    {
        filterData.remove(_col);
    }
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------
    void
    setFilter(QHash<int, QString> _value)
    {
        filterData.clear();

        QHashIterator<int, QString> it(_value);
        while (it.hasNext())
        {
            it.next();
            setFilterValue(it.key(), it.value());
        }

        invalidateFilter();
    }
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------
    void setFilterValue(int _col, QString _value)
    {
        filterData.insert(_col, QRegExp(_RegExpString(_value)));
    }
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------
    void beginSorting()
    {
        invalidateFilter();
    }

protected:
    bool filterAcceptsRow(int sourceRow, const QModelIndex &sourceParent) const;

private:
    QString stringEkvival;
    QString _RegExpString(const QString _value) const;
    QHash<int, QRegExp> filterData;
    bool dateInRange(const QDate &date) const;

};
#endif //MULTIFILTERPROXIMODEL_H
```

Test.pro

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2015-08-10T16:08:24
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core
QT       += gui
QT       += sql

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = DataBase
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
    customfiltersort.cpp \
    smulifilterproxymodel.cpp \
    database.cpp \
        mainwindow.cpp \
    database.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h \
    customfiltersort.h \
    smulifilterproxymodel.h \
    database.h \
    database.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui
```

Comment: Класс customfiltersort я взял с какого-то сайта

Comment: proxyModel = new CustomFilterSort(this); // Может проблема в том, что вы не создали объект унаследованного класса?

Comment: В классе `SMuliFilterProxyModel` надо вместо `res &=` использовать `res &&= ...`, или `res = res && ...` и while должен быть без `&& res` и, конечно, чтобы его использовать - его надо создать )

Comment: Если я создаю объект CustomFilterSort вместо QSortFilterProxyModel то таблица вообще пустой становится) http://prntscr.com/tr5849

Comment: Вот классы которые я использую @AlexanderChernin http://prntscr.com/tr59f9

Comment: Добавьте код в вопрос - лень бегать по ссылкам

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-itemviews-customsortfiltermodel-example.html - пример фильтрации по нескольким параметрам

Comment: Видел этот пример фильтрации. Но не понимаю совсем как перенести его на свой проект. @e.n.shirokov.

Comment: Добавил код в вопрос @AlexanderChernin

Comment: И где изменения с учетом комментариев, которые вам уже даны. Это первое. Второе, в классе CustomFilterSort  нет фильтров, соответствующих столбцам, а должно быть как в SMuliFilterProxyModel с учетом моего комментария ранее. Попробуйте переделать, не получится - приходите

Comment: Если я правильно понял, SMuliFilterProxyModel и CustomFilterSort два похожих класса. Нужно использовать только один из них. Где вы создали объект SMuliFilterProxyModel?

Comment: Похожи они тем что наследуются от одного класса - QSortFilterProxyModel. Я не создавал объект класса SMuliFilterProxyModel. Потому что там находится не ясная для меня переменная под именем notFound. Которая не объявлена. Соответственно я не знаю каким значением её инициализировать @e.n.shirokov.

Comment: В общем попытался @AlexanderChernin. Не совсем понимаю как сделать фильтры в CustomFilterSort. Переделал функцию _RegExpString в SMuliFilterProxyModel как Вы сказали. Также делал proxyModel = new CustomFilterSort(this); в функции createUI класса mainwindow как говорил shirokov, заменяю объект класса QSortFilterProxyModel на CustomFilterSort, то таблица выводится совсем пустой. Код изменил в вопросе и на яндекс диске.

Comment: В общем поковырялся я ещё немного в коде и вот что вышло. Я добавил создание конструктора SMuliFilterProxyModel. Теперь вместо QSortFilterProxyModel *proxyModel; я создаю SMuliFilterProxyModel *proxyModel; в mainwindow.h. Ещё полностью поменял функции изменения текста в полях QLineEdit (все 4 функции). Прописал в каждой из них это:
    proxyModel->beginSorting(); //Для первой
    proxyModel->setFilterValue(1,arg1);

    proxyModel->beginSorting(); //Для второй
    proxyModel->setFilterValue(2,arg1);

И так далее.. Теперь когда я запускаю программу и ввожу фильтры выходит такая ошибка

Comment: http://prntscr.com/trbmem Эта ошибка вылетает постоянно каждый раз после того как я ввожу любой символ в фильтр над столбцом. НО что самое классное программа работает и множественная фильтрация тоже вроде как. Как бы исправить эту ошибку? Я видимо что то не так делаю с вызовом функций у класса SMuliFilterProxyModel @AlexanderChernin Код сейчас обновлю на сайте